# can users access the SharePoint application page who have read permissions?

Tags: sharepoint

we created one page and placed under LAYOUTS folder.so can u tell me can all users access this page by giving their AD credentials.

some users are not able to login to this page.
pleage give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

The default Application Page setup will require the View Application Pages permission, and all derived permissions. You can manually configure the permissions of the application page by defining the [RightsRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.rightsrequired.aspx) property of the page. This is usually defined OnLoadComplete, but you can specify to occur after OnPreInitComplete by configuring the [RightsCheckMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.rightscheckmode.aspx) property.

But, without fiddling in these settings, it is still possible that certain users who have the read permissions on the general site may be barred from the Application Page. This can arise whenever you have controls that require different permission levels. For example, if you have a custom application page that has a field control associated with a specific list and item, if that control is in Edit mode then the user needs Edit permissions for that list and item in order to view the application page. It does not actually matter if this field control has anything to do with the list in question! For example, I once had an application page designed for bulk-downloading files which are in two folders. I wanted to re-use this page for a few different document libraries, so I decided to create a custom multi-lookup field control that would take the List query string as if on a New Form, and build the list of items to download that way. But this page was blocked for a subset of users who were not allowed New item permissions in one of the two folders, even though the page technically didn't do anything involving adding new items.

Any other elements on the page which require a separate set of permissions than general site permissions will also interfere, but the general case is with item-level and list-level permissions conflicting with the site-level permission. Simply check all of your controls, especially ones based on SharePoint web controls. As long as the user has permissions necessary to operate all of these, the user should be able to view the application page.

Answer (score 2):

The entire user who has read permission, they can access this page.

If this page trying to do any manipulation, which needs hire permission, you may get access denied.

For trouble shooting comment all cods and try to access this page with read permission.